# Replace a word in MySql database

Tags: mysql, database, replace

Hi
Is there a way to write a sql statement to search and replace a word in a mySql database?
For example Find "word1" in "testDatabase" and replace it with "word2".

Comment: Is "word1" in a varchar column or somewhere in a clob?  The answer would greatly change the answer to the question and the ease of solution.

Comment: @duffymo will I'm not really sure about it, but Let's say it's a varchar in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tables = table_list;

foreach($tables as $t)
mysql_query("Update $t SET wordcol = 'word2' WHERE wordcol = 'word1'
```

If it's more complicated than that you should look at not changing the sql and simply altering the phrasing in the php/html when that word gets output.

You could even do something like:

```
function my_sql_fetch($query){
$fetch = mysql_query($query);
$return = array();
while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){
  foreach($rec as &$val)
    str_replace('word1', 'word2', $val);
  $return[] = $rec;
  }
return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update statement like this

```
update colname = 'word2' where colname = 'word1'
```

Comment: will I was thinking of something more general than updating each table in the database and setting all columns.

Comment: eitherway you need to use update statement in query, if you can give more examples could give more suggestions